# Установка плагина Tomcat в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, плагин

Доброго времени суток.
Скачал и установил Tomcat 7.0.39 c официального сайта версию `32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer` работает как надо.
Хочу теперь установить плагин для Eclipse, везде в интернете пишут, что где-то в архиве с Tomcat должна быть папка с плагином, которую надо скопировать в `eclipse/plugins`.
Скачал Tomcat просто zip архивом, но там тоже нет никакой папки с плагином.
Как установить плагин?

Comment: лучше через eclipse marketplace

Comment: по сути они отличаются только начальным набором плагинов но так тоже можно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался- у меня был `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers` и в нем в настройках не было вкладки `server`, скачал `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` и в нем эта вкладочка есть.
Дальше справлюсь, всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: `Windows -> preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Search` и указать папку с томкатом. если не найдет значит скорее за все плагин для томката не установлен. В том же окне жмем `Add` (если в списке адаптеров есть нужный вам можете попробовать добавить вручную) в противном случае жмем `Download additional server adapters` и выбираем нужный.